# How to access array in asyncTimes?Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have a for loop which has array of values once that iteration ends i need to pass the array values to async.Times with two callback,how to handle this kind of scenario in nodejs

**Example**

```
    var date = 20;
    var myarray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
        myarray[i] = date;
        date++;
    }
    async.times(n,function(){
        myfunction(n,function(err,date){
            next(err,date)
        },function(err,date){
    });
```

here date array should passed is that possible?

Comment: Are you about to loop on array and access one element in every function call? For example each time myFunction called gets a value from array.

Comment: @rselvaganesh: In that case, you should not use `times` but rather `map` (or `each`, or their sequential variants). Otherwise, just access the `array` variable via closure.

Comment: @Bergi if it possible can u please fiddle it

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass to `myfunction`, the array values (`date`, 20...24)? Then just use `async.map(myfunction, function(err,results){})`